# How to override css classes other than in app.scss in ionic?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am designing a dark theme for my ionic application by following this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgYfGHG7bQc). It works for most of the classes but, there are some css classes which only change when i override them in app.scss, if i override them in theme.dark.scss they remain unaffected.

for example here's an ionic alert class **.alert-md .alert-wrapper**

if i change the **background-color** and **color** in app.scss, it reflects the changes. But, if i do the same in theme.dark.scss, it doesn't do anything.

I've tried using **!important** in theme.dark.scss but still it doesnt change the background-color and color of that class.

Is there any way to override the css in the **theme.dark.scss** file?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can change your background color in `variables.scss` or override the background color

Comment: Could you please explain how? I overrided my backgroudn color but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

In Variable.css you would find and change as below:-

```
// From
@import "ionic.theme.default";

// To
@import "ionic.theme.dark";
```

This would make you theme dark and then you can make appropriate changes as needed.

Please follow below link for more explanation.

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/117/How-to-Properly-Use-Ionic-Theme-Variables

Comment: I checked that out but it just changes the base theme to dark. What i want is to manually change the css classes of the components in my created theme.dark.scss

Comment: @K.Ajay. Please check the following link
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/creating-custom-alerts-in-ionic/49723/10